# Wsimport on OSX -> NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/internal/ws/util/localization/LocalizableMessageFactory

Tags: java, macos, soap, wsimport

On OSX with Java 8, if I call the command

```
wsimport
```

I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/internal/ws/util/localization/LocalizableMessageFactory
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.resources.WscompileMessages.<clinit>(WscompileMessages.java:40)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportOptions.validate(WsimportOptions.java:263)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:120)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport.main(WsImport.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.localization.LocalizableMessageFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
```

If I try the command to check the version:

```
wsimport -version
```

it throws no error and shows me the version:

```
JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01
```

Is this any known error or is there any fix/workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched back to java version 6 and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Java 8.
when i ran wsimport I first got an error, that a mainclass was missing.
I then tried cleaning up my path / classpath as @Angelo Fuchs mentioned.
wsimport then came up with the same NoClassDefFoundError @Jan had.

In the end I reinstalled a fully new SDK including the jdk and the jre, making sure both were installed in different locations because I was affraid the installers would overwrite files in the installation directory of the jdk, because the jdk installer already created a directory named "jre"

After the reinstall all was fine

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

For me it was that the `java` command was started with Java 8, but the `classpath` contained Java 7 jars.

After I made sure to fix the JAVA Environment variables etc. to all point to the same Java, it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

close the eclipse and delete your "target" folder it is placed in your project directory and open eclipse run in maven clean